# package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am a beginner in react native. Right now I am trying to integrate https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/ library to my react-native application. for now, I am targeting only the Android platform.

I have performed all the steps that are mentioned in the documentation but when I tried to run on an application using `react-native run-android` it gives me the below error.

`error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist`

I understand the meaning of error it is saying that this package doesn't exist in my project but this package I installed from npm and it exists in the node module.

I am using the latest version of Nodejs and npm and below is the package.json dependency.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.6",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
},
```

Full Error:

```
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainActivity.java:19: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
                                ^
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class NavigationActivity
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:12: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
                                ^
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:13: error: package com.reactnativenavigation.react does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
                                      ^
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:14: error: package com.reactnativenavigation.react does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.ReactGateway;
                                      ^
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
                                     ^
  symbol: class NavigationApplication
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
              ^
  symbol:   class ReactGateway
  location: class MainApplication
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:53: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class NavigationReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:56: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
            @Override
            ^
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
        return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
                   ^
  symbol:   class ReactGateway
  location: class MainApplication
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:64: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
E:\data\code\practise\react-native\reactNativeStart\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativestart\MainApplication.java:77: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
13 errors
```

Comment: if you are a beginner please go with [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). It's way easier. If you want the native navigation with react-navigation you can install [react-native-screens](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens), but it will work fine without it.

Comment: @Ziyo react-navigtation is a bad library man. You can't even do stacks properly in it. It doesn't even have reset built in (with animation)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe downgrading is a good solution. I had this issue, I am assuming you are still on React Native 60+ (0.61 in my case). I solved it by ignoring flavours to all previous versions except for RN 60. I believe it has something to do with plugins for all the versions listed in the if block being ignored.

So in your `android/build.gradle` have the code below down the bottom

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (
                            names.contains("reactNative51") ||
                            names.contains("reactNative55") ||
                            names.contains("reactNative56") ||
                            names.contains("reactNative57") ||
                            names.contains("reactNative57_5") 
                            // names.contains("reactNative60")
                    ) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may run into an error after about unrecognised symbols in `MainApplication.java` where the doc is also providing the wrong information.

In your MainApplication.java below should be your MainApplication Method. I have changed the getPackages() method to RN's original method as in RN 60 the method that RNN uses has type errors

```
public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

    @Override
    protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
        ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
            @Override
            protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
                return "index";
            }
        };
        return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDebug() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return getPackages();
    }
}
```

Comment: commenting out `names.contains("reactNative60")` worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It has react-native-navigation package error. the package does not import properly use android studio. if have any package issue the android stdio will show the issue.

the best way is you use android studio,

> Open android studio -> open your project android folder-> and sync your project-> go to Mainapplication.java-> you can import plugin via android studio.

sync again it will fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had changed some local environment variables. Running:

```
yarn install
```

In my react native directory did the trick. Built as normal. If you are using npm: it would be :

```
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem. I tried everything with no result. My version of react native was 0.60.0 and I downgraded it to 0.57.0, repeat the steps in https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=android and everything was allright.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Put the solution here instead of link.

Comment: "repeat the steps in ..." - namely this is bad. Put the description here, what should be done. All answers on SO should be understandable and sufficient without opening any links. Links can provide additional info. But the answer should be understandable *without* links. That's why please extend your answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had some problem too and I really don't know what it is. I reinstall react native project and repeat all steps in manual (https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=android). After that, 'build' started work))

Comment: "repeat the steps in ..." - namely this is bad. Put the description here, what should be done. All answers on SO should be understandable and sufficient without opening any links. Links can provide additional info. But the answer should be understandable *without* links. That's why please extend your answer.